# Can I use normalization and standardization on the same dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, normalization, standardization, feature-scaling

I'm working on an ML project to predict wine quality from a wine's physical characteristics. The features of my data are on vastly different scales so I've been experimenting with different normalization/standardization techniques to see how these impact the data.

Originally the features are like so:

[image: Feature Ranges before any transformations]

After taking the natural log of all the features and then applying z-score normalisation, the features look like so:

[image: Feature scale after taking log of features then standardizing them]

This seems a lot better to me, but this is my first ML project and I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious, or wether or not it is mathematically sensible to perform the transformations I have.

Can I normalize and standardize my data?
Do the transformations I have performed make sense together?
Should I drop the example with the extreme density value, if my model is sensitive to feature magnitude?

Comment: A better question is why you are doing this? Or why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: I've learned in my classes on ML that vastly different feature ranges can be problematic if your model is sensitive to feature magnitudes, and can also slow down the time to converge when using gradient descent.

I believe I'm going to use a linear regression model, so (I think?) these two concerns would be justified. Beyond that, it's also a requirement of the project that I discuss data preprocessing, and feature scaling seemed like a relevant data transformation.

Comment: When using gradients or penalization this will be an issue, but (ordinary) linear regression does not use either, so this is not necessary.

Comment: What would the case be if I were to use a model that does use gradients/penalization?

Comment: If by 'normalize' you mean 'scale to unit length' (vector [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)) then you can't standardize and normalize the same variable, they're trying to do different things. If by 'normalize' you mean 'use some transformation to make the distribution closer to normal' then both things can be done to the same variable. However it's not clear why you really need to  make variables marginally normal; standardizing does make sense if you want to use regularization, say, and may be useful for some fitting algorithms,